# Positional parameter 'set'

Tags: unix

Can someone please tell me the difference between the below 2 commands -

$ set 1 2 3 4 5

$ set -- 1 2 3 4 5

I am using the first type of command in a shell script, which is behaving awkwardly. But the 2nd command is working fine. Don't understand what's the difference.

Comment: When you call set with variables, like `set "${myexample}"` this will work until the value of your variable starts with a `-`.  This will be treated as a flag, see @chepner for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But I am not quite clear. Can you please show an example? So far I cud not find any difference. See below -

$ name1=walter; name2=thomas; name3=daniel

$ set ${name1} ${name2} ${name3}

$ echo $*
walter thomas daniel

$ set -- ${name1} ${name2} ${name3}

$ echo $*
walter thomas daniel

Comment: name1="-negativ", name2="+positiv" name3="--doubleminus"

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in this example; the first five positional parameters are set to the numbers 1 through 5 in each case. The `--` tells `set` to stop processing its own flags, allowing you to set a positional parameter with a value that would otherwise be treated as a flag to `set`:

Consider

```
set -f    # Disable globbing
```

vs

```
set -- -f  # Set $1 to the string "-f"
```